Using st_buffer and st_intersection on geocode point geometries in R
I am starting with a CSV of addresses that have been put through a geocoding software to give lat and long. I want to turn that in an sf object, create a buffer and see the intersections with polygon geometries in a FEMA Flood Zone shape file. I have run this operation on the point geometries only and it works beautifully, but I need now to check for intersections with a larger area, hence the use of st_buffer on the point geometries. The result I get when the buffers are used is difficult to interpret and seems to indicate I am doing something entirely wrong to get my desired result. In this example I would expect to get less than 3 rows (probably just 1) for each buffered point because neither of these locations intersects with a flood zone. Instead, I get many, many rows for each point.
Shape file for flood zone found here,
click on "Expand All" and look for "NFHL Data-County" data for a zip file with shapefiles.
library(sf)

# read data and create data frame of point geometry, coerce to sf
properties_df <- data.frame(Name = c("House", "Office"), 
                            Longitude = c("-80.133573", "-80.177333"), 
                            Latitude = c("39.500773", "39.471715"))

properties_sf <- st_as_sf(properties_df, 
                          coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), 
                          crs = 4269)

# get flood zones
fema <- read_sf("S_FLD_HAZ_AR.shp")

# verify sf object can be transformed to EPSG:4269
st_can_transform(properties_sf, 4269)

# transform sf object to crs 4269
properties_sf <- st_transform(properties_sf, crs = 4269)

# create 100 m buffer around points in properties_sf
properties_buffer <- st_buffer(properties_sf, dist = 100)

# find intersections between fema and properties_buffer
fema_properties <- st_intersection(properties_buffer, fema)




Hard to tell what's going wrong for you without your data. Plus there's things like your first line creating properties_df which never gets used in the rest of the code, although properties appears from nowhere - should they be the same thing? The buffers look okay generated from that. Sample data and some plots or tables showing what's going wrong are really needed.

I found a shapefile with the same name here https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/flood-hazard-area (zip file, uncompressed to SHP etc) but it doesn't overlap with your data points, being in the -100 longitudes where your sample data points are -80s. Intersection returns an empty set...

thanks @spacedman. Let me know if these edits help.

Helps a bit. I'm not certain I've got the right shapefile since that page is a bit...complex. I got a thing with PRODUCT_ID NFHL_54049C which was 54049C_20240413.zip. With the shapefile from that I don't get the results you do. I only get two rows, both of which are intersections with the feature where FLD_AR_ID is 54049C_441. The only thing I do different is the fema data needs running through fema = st_make_valid(fema) to stop some geometry errors breaking the intersection.

Thanks @Spacedman. Is that wrapped by st_intersection or a transformation to the fema object beforehand, or does it not matter?

Directly after reading fema from the shapefile, I use st_make_valid. You could do this in one step: fema = st_make_valid(st_read("filename.shp"))

@Spacedman I got the result I expected by changing the distance of the buffer to 0.001 which makes me think the units are km but when I do st_crs(properties_buffer) I see "LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]". I interpreted that to mean the units are meters.

I don't know what you are doing now, but that doesn't tie up with your code that creates properties_buffer in your question. Its is in crs 4269 which is lat-long so the distance gets interpreted as metres. Try b = 100; units(b) = "m"; buf = st_buffer(properties_sf, dist=b); plot(buf$geometry) and you should see two circles that are 100m radius.

@gritzngravy: I don't get this whole idea of reprojecting your features since sf::st_crs(properties_sf) == sf::st_crs(fema) returns TRUE.

I cannot replicate this behaviour using your data but it's also not 100 % clear  which object your attached screenshots are representing (fema_properties, I guess). That's one of the reasons why it is discouraged to add screenshots instead of actual code and/or console output.
However, in case of doubt if your code really returns the desired output, always make sure to double check visually what you're actually doing - either via plot() or by dumping your vector data to disk using st_write() and checking interactively in e.g. QGIS.
Based on geometry given, a complex intersect situation is not to be expected:
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# read data and create data frame of point geometry, coerce to sf
properties_df <- data.frame(Name = c("House", "Office"), 
                            Longitude = c("-80.133573", "-80.177333"), 
                            Latitude = c("39.500773", "39.471715"))

properties_sf <- st_as_sf(properties_df, 
                          coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), 
                          crs = 4269)

# get flood zones, make geometry valid by fixing duplicate vertices
fema <- read_sf("S_FLD_HAZ_AR.shp") |> st_make_valid()

# create 100 m buffer around points in properties_sf
properties_buffer <- st_buffer(properties_sf, dist = 100)

# inspect
st_geometry(properties_buffer) |> plot()
st_geometry(properties_sf) |> plot(col = "red", add = TRUE, pch = 20)
st_geometry(fema) |> plot(border = "blue", add = TRUE)


And now you can "clip" your fema object by properties_buffer making use of st_intersection() preserving attributes of both objects and the geometry of the latter. Since both buffers target the same fema object (c.f. DFIRM_ID, ZONE_SUBTY == "AREA OF MINIMAL FLOOD HAZARD"), attributes are replicated apart from Name, being part of your original properties_sf:
# find intersections between fema and properties_buffer
st_intersection(properties_buffer, fema) 
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 20 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -80.1785 ymin: 39.47081 xmax: -80.1324 ymax: 39.50168
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#>     Name DFIRM_ID VERSION_ID  FLD_AR_ID STUDY_TYP FLD_ZONE
#> 1  House   54049C    1.1.1.0 54049C_441        NP        X
#> 2 Office   54049C    1.1.1.0 54049C_441        NP        X
#>                     ZONE_SUBTY SFHA_TF STATIC_BFE V_DATUM DEPTH LEN_UNIT
#> 1 AREA OF MINIMAL FLOOD HAZARD       F      -9999    <NA> -9999     <NA>
#> 2 AREA OF MINIMAL FLOOD HAZARD       F      -9999    <NA> -9999     <NA>
#>   VELOCITY VEL_UNIT AR_REVERT AR_SUBTRV BFE_REVERT DEP_REVERT DUAL_ZONE
#> 1    -9999     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      -9999      -9999      <NA>
#> 2    -9999     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      -9999      -9999      <NA>
#>    SOURCE_CIT                       geometry
#> 1 54049C_FIS1 POLYGON ((-80.13309 39.4999...
#> 2 54049C_FIS1 POLYGON ((-80.17634 39.4712...


Yeah, this is the same behaviour I got as noted in comments. No idea what we are doing differently.

@Spacedman Unfortunately I noticed your comment only after I posted this... But at least the result is the same :)
